# Using $WINDOWID in bash script

Tags: linux, bash, terminal, script

I am writing script to grab the coordinates of all terminals via `xwininfo` and write them to a file, however while running the command on its own in a terminal works fine, using it in a bash script or even a C++ `system()` call results in a "-id requires argument" error.

Script:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo $NULL > /etc/WallFade/termInfo
i=1

while test -e "/dev/pts/$i"
do
        echo "/dev/pts/$i"
        echo $WINDOWID
        xwininfo -id $WINDOWID | grep -E 'Absolute upper-left X:  [0-9]{0,4}' | grep -Eo '[0-9]{0,4}' > /dev/pts/$i >> /etc/WallFade/termInfo
        xwininfo -id $WINDOWID | grep -E 'Absolute upper-left Y:  [0-9]{0,4}' | grep -Eo '[0-9]{0,4}' > /dev/pts/$i >> /etc/WallFade/termInfo
        let "i++"
sleep 1s
done
```

The `echo $WINDOWID` line produces no output, and I don't know why when that too gives output outside of a script.

Comment: How do you run the script? E.g. `sudo` doesn't preserve the existing environment by default.

Comment: It was sudo, so I'll have to take that into consideration.

Also, I appear to have been mistaken, $WINDOWID is interpreted before being sent to the terminal, so "xwininfo -id $WINDOWID > /dev/pts/x" will always return the information of the terminal that the command was run in and NOT /dev/pts/x.

Any ideas on how to keep the variable from being interpreted before it's sent over to the terminal?

Comment: Even if you keep the variable from being interpreted before it's sent to another terminal, it won't be interpreted there. What you send to `/dev/pts/N` is *displayed*, not executed in the other terminal. Or it would be displayed. The last redirection (`>>`) wins, so I think you send nothing to the other terminal anyway.

Comment: Maybe start from the other direction with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/252906/how-to-get-the-list-of-open-windows-from-xserver but then IIRC it's not straightforward to get the associated process for each window.

Answer (score 0):

You need the list of window ids, which you can get with "`xwininfo -tree -root`".

For example, this shows the upper-left corner of my 7 open Xterms:

```
for id in `xwininfo -tree -root | grep -i xterm | awk '{print $1}'` ; do xwininfo -id $id | grep 'Absolute upper-left X' ; done
  Absolute upper-left X:  1033
  Absolute upper-left X:  821
  Absolute upper-left X:  8
  Absolute upper-left X:  1687
  Absolute upper-left X:  7
  Absolute upper-left X:  520
  Absolute upper-left X:  7
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).